# Simulate electrical loads vs time in a institutional building

Tags: load, outlet

I would like to simulate how electrical loads behave in an institutional building.
For example, if we have 2 panel boards Pb-A and Pb-B which have the following loads:
Pb-A: 10 lighting circuits 120 v with 100 lights in total each x 25 watt; 15 outlet 120 v circuits each with with 8 180-va outlet for general use and 4 208 v circuit for instant water heaters, each at 7 kw
Pb-B 6 3-Phase AHU having each one 5 Hp compresor load and one 2 hp fan coil load

Any hint on how to approach this project would be highly appreciated (considering that most of the assumptions should require knowledge on how the institution works, so the focus should be how to translate the assumptions into simulation formulas)

For example, if “normally” 50% of the outlets are using for 100 va loads, while 10% are using for 600 va loads, 20% for 50 va loads and the remaining 20% for loads between 10 va and 300 va, how a predictive formula can be construed (ie assumming Gaussian distribution??)

Comment: Sounds similar, but not the same as Erlang trunk theory. That mostly uses tables because the equations are too cumbersome to contantly re-calculate.

Comment: Thanks DKNguyen, that is a good hint, however, while Erlang address binary loads (is either the phone is calling or not) the case I’m trying to solve is a bit more complicated as we need to considered the load magnitude and type which should be associated with some typical behavior